# Где лежат стандартные иконки для Spinner?

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-spinner

В какой папке лежат стандартные иконки для `Spinner`? `layout` файлы для него же лежат по пути `Android SDK\platforms\android-15\data\res\layout`, значит и иконки где-то не далеко.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Графика стандартных виджетов на устройстве находится в файле `freamwork-res.apk`.

Если вам требуются образцы графики стандартных виджетов, как основа для кастомизации виджетов, то проще всего их получить в проекте средствами самой IDE.

В боковой панели *Project* откройте отображение *Project*, затем раскройте пункт *External Libraries* - здесь будут ресурсы всех внешних библиотек, подключенных к вашему проекту, в том числе и ресурсы SDK - откройте подпапку `res/`, там вы найдете все ресурсы для подключенной к проекту версии SDK, в том числе и графику в папках `drawable` и аналогичных с квалификаторами `-hdpi`,`-xhdpi` и тд.
Теперь вы можете просто скопировать оттуда нужное в папку `res/drawable` вашего проекта простым перетаскиванием мышкой (с зажатой клавишей CTRL - Copy File) и после изменить, как вам требуется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если говорить о расположении на диске, то графические файлы ресурсов находятся  (версия SDK зависит от установленных на ваш компьютер через SDK Manager):

```
\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res\drawable
```

а так же в папках с квалификаторами: `drawable-hdpi`,`drawable-xhdpi` и тд.

Конкретно ресурсы спиннера начинаются с собственно *spinner_* и включают множество файлов ресурсов, как графических, так и селекторов и проч.