# Как правильно создать стиль для вью?

Tags: java, android

В приложении есть `TextView` и для них я настроил тени, цвет и толщину вот так

```
android:shadowColor="@color/black_color"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/ntz_color_yellow"
```

потом вью элементов стало больше и больше и теперь уже не удобно для каждой писать лишних 6 строк.

Как это можно вынести в стиль? Как найти значения в стилях которые соответвуют значениям которые прописываеш в XML для вью?

Answer (score 4):

В файл *res/values/styles.xml* добавляешь свой стиль:

```
<style name="styleMyButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button"> >
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_background_selector</item>
   <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
   <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

Значения в стилях соответствуют именам атрибутов. Лучше всего стиль наследовать от того `View`, для которого этот стиль будет применятся - это позволит "подхватить" атрибуты по умолчанию. Здесь наследование от стиля для кнопки `Button`

Затем используешь:

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       style="@style/styleMyButton"
       android:text="@string/text_button1"/>

<Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       style="@style/styleMyButton"
       android:text="@string/text_button2"/>
```

Не лишним будет [изучать файл styles.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) фреймворка Android (и\или [библиотеки AppCompat](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles.xml), если используется она), чтобы узнать все доступные для переопределения атрибуты (для изменения дефолтных значений), так же вы естественно можете добавлять свои атрибуты.
Так же вы можете получить доступ к файлам *styles.xml* системы прямо в IDE способом, [аналогичным этому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462326/177345), только проследоать нужно до папки *res/values/*